# Python: Can't fill in values in worksheet table in Origin Pro

Tags: python, originlab

Im trying to create an automation with python helping with creating graphs in Origin Pro from data from excel files. I figures out how to specify the data I want Origin Pro to create graphs from in the excel sheets but I can't figure out how to get the values into the columns of the worksheet. Maybe someone knows their way around Origin Pro and might be able to help.
Very new to this, excuse obvious newbie mistakes please! Thanks in advance:)

```
#ORIGINPRO

#open Origin Pro

subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files\OriginLab\Origin2023b\Origin64.exe"])

#Wait for open

time.sleep(5)

#start Origin Pro in the background

op.new()


# Prepare data.

list1 = lists_from_rows[0]

data = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
data2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 

# Prepare worksheet.
wks=op.new_sheet()

# Put data to col(A), and set Long Name, Units, designation as well
wks.Columns(0)[:] = data
wks.Columns(1)[:] = data2

graph = wks.plot(type="scatter", axes=['left','bottom'])
```

Thats the part where the data should be put into the worksheet. The lists are random, I tried to simply the lists so its easier to figure out why it doesnt work. I tried the following first, instead of wks.Columns but it didnt work either.

```
wks.from_list('A', data, 'Charge', '+', axis='N')
wks.from_list('B', data1, axis='X')
```

If I run my snippet, it doesn't throw an error, it just seems to run endlessly.

I tried to do the #Put data to col(A)... part differently like I described above and also aks chatgpt but it also cant provide anything to solve it.